# Default SQL Server Session for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

When opening a .bdy(/sql/vew/..)-File in IntelliJ, it always greets me with semantic errors for almost every line. That is because it needs a dbsession to check the references against. DataGrip behaves identical.

For reference:

[image]

Can I somehow state a default here per file/dir/proj/global?

Comment: Also, it looks like Oracle dialect is set as default. You can see it in top right corner. Default dialect can be changed here File | Settings | Database | SQL Dialects (Global)

Comment: I actually have to deal with pl/sql procedures in my job, so oracle is to pick here. Yet IJs subset of SqlDeveloper's features seems to cover most of the project'S requirements, so I'm currently trying to stick to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | SQL Resolution Scopes, here you can specify global Project Mapping to data source/database/schema, or define mapping for any directory/file.
in DataGrip setting path will be as follow File | Settings | Database | SQL Resolution Scopes.